# Should I double up on an LQP review comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality-posts, deletion

When reviewing Low-Quality Posts on EL&U I often find that someone has previously reviewed it and posted the relevant comment '*from Review*'. When I come to recommending deletion, should I re-post the needed comment (for the sake of analytics and emphasis) or just recommend deletion without a comment.

Normally, I just up-vote the previous comment and recommend deletion; is this the best course of action?

What do you do?

Is it possible that, instead of creating a new comment, the system automatically up-votes the comment that is already there, like the duplicate system?

Comment: Yes, I do what you do.

Comment: There is no official analytics of deletion reasons available to high-reputation users or moderators, though you can theoretically do this with the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hold the phone!

I have just voted in the same way as the person before me in [a LQP review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/216212) and I can confirm that, at the moment, when you double up on a vote...  nothing happens.

As such, the premise of this question is sort of undermined; just go ahead and double up on a vote, nothing bad is going to happen.

Answer (score 10):

> Normally, I just up-vote the previous comment and recommend deletion; is this the best course of action? What do you do? My only worry with doing that is if it skews the analytics of which option has been chosen.

I almost always upvote comments I agree with, and then choose "no comment needed" when I "recommend deletion". If there isn't one already, I'd post a comment myself.

Most of the time I post comments using ["SE auto comments"](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/37743) Chrome extension, other times I use ELU's canned comments "from review".

About the analytics, I have no idea. Maybe a moderator can answer that part.

> Is it possible that, instead of creating a new comment, the system automatically up-votes the comment that is already there, like the duplicate system?

The system neither adds a duplicate comment, nor upvotes the existing ones.

Comment: Yes, I use that extension too. My only worry with doing that is if it skews the analytics of which option has been chosen. However,  in the long run, that probably doesn't matter.

Comment: About the analytics, I have no idea. Maybe a moderator can answer that part. :)